# Dragging a DataGrid row INTO other DataGrid row

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, drag-and-drop

I have 2 datagrids, and the way the standard dragging is implemented I don't know if it is easy to provide underneath feature:

I want to drag 1 datagrid row from the second DataGrid INTO a row from the first DataGrid.
You can easily set-up a drag & drop functionality, but that seems to only work to place the row above or under a row in the other DataGrid.

When dragging is enabled, the row in the other DataGrid has to light up, and if the drag is finished by releasing the mouse, the row should be added INTO that row.

Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/09/19/dragging-rows-between-two-different-flex-datagrid-controls/

Hope this help you out.